# Not getting 2D list in google colab?

Tags: python, numpy, google-colaboratory

Why I got this output in Google Colab ?

```
import numpy as np
f = np.array([[34,23,4,23,4],[23,34,234,23]])
print(f)
```

output :

```
[list([34, 23, 4, 23, 4]) list([23, 34, 234, 23])]
```

instead of :

```
[ [34  23  4, 23  4] 
   [23  34  234  23] ]
```

[enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not about google colab. In any environment you get the same output because the 2D array in numpy has a fixed dimension and in your case rows have different lengths. The output is one-dimensional array with the dtype=object which only keeps references to lists. However, this is not what numpy optimized for.

Tl,dr: Because your sublists have different lengths.

Comment: Just Omg.Lol.I just checked everything to find why .  What i can say . Thank you Man

Comment: Sure, if this solved your problem, please consider accepting it as an answer.